# How to form a numpy array of elements in a loop?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a function that returns `numpy.ndarray`. This function is being called in a loop. I would like access to all the `numpy.ndarrays` after the loop is over so that I can perform numpy operations.

pseudo code:

```
for x in something:
   rects = method_that_returns_numpy_arrays()

#at this point I would like access to all the rects collected when the loop ends
```

I tried putting them in a list:

```
all_rects = []
for x in something:  
   rects = method_that_returns_numpy_arrays()
   all_rects.append(rects)

#now all_rects is a list containing numpy arrays
#but now I can't perform numpy functions such as 
#np.column_stack([all_rects[:,0], all_rects[:,1], all_rects[:,2]+all_rects[:,0], all_rects[:,3]+all_rects[:,1]])
```

**Questions**

How can I get a numpy array of all `rects` after the loop ends? I should add that I don't have access to change `method_that_returns_numpy_arrays`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.column_stack`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html) to concatenate all of the rects that are in the list into a 2D array.

```
all_rects = [np.arange(4), np.arange(5, 9)]
rect_array = np.column_stack(all_rects)

    array([[0, 5],
           [1, 6],
           [2, 7],
           [3, 8]])
```

To get the values that you're trying to get (by adding element 0 to element 2 and element 1 to element 4). We can do the following using the new numpy array.

```
rect_array[2,:] += rect_array[0,:]
rect_array[4,:] += rect_array[1,:]
```

Comment: When I print `all_rects` I see this `[array([ 59, 119, 175,  14], dtype=int32), array([147, 107,  66,  11], dtype=int32)]`. now when I do `rect_array = np.column_stack(all_rects) ` I see them stacked as columns but that is not my intent. I finally want `(59,119,234,133),(147,107,213,118)` I am adding element 2 with 0 and element 3 with 1.

Comment: @Anthony I have updated my answer to provide an explicit example of how you can do this operation. What my original answer showed was how to convert your rects into a numpy array which you can then interact with in the way that you said that you wanted to in your question.